# Time or Number picker Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: timepicker, seconds

I make some app for Windows Phone 8.1. And actually I want TimePicker with seconds. 
I can't install WP toolkit. Probably because it for WP8, and I can't create my custom LoopingSelector because it sealed now.
Is there any other ways to get picker with seconds?